# Is it possible to get a remote computer process and waitForInputIdle over it? c#

Tags: c#, process, wmi, loading

So I would like to run something similar to the following on a remote computer:

```
 process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
 process.WaitForInputIdle();
```

I have no problem connecting via WMI, executing processes and running query on them but I cant find a way to WaitForInputIdle on these remote processes. (or any other method that tells me that the process has finished loading)

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: Short of running a remote process that calls `WaitForInputIdle` locally, this is probably not possible. Why do you think you need it? This function is intended to [help port 16-bit DDE applications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/). It may not do what you expect it to do. Is there anything you're doing with the process that fails when you try to do it after `.Start()`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert  I am testing performance impact on processes that are being injected with code during their launch phase. So far this method proved to be useful in finding issues. However, If you have any other idea of how to go about this,  I will be more than happy to hear about it! Cheers.